# How to plot hysteresis loop using excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have data like this:

0,00000     -0,17278    -2,30557

0,05000     -0,16098    -2,28972

0,10000     -0,15170    -2,27128

0,15000     -0,13824    -2,25024

0,20000     -0,12830    -2,22890 ...

I need to plot hysteresis, something like this:

[image]

Is that possible in excel, and if yes how exactly with these 3 types of data?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close, I think.

First, order your data so the hysteresis path is defined. Excel plots points in the order that they are listed. I sorted the second set of points in descending order and appended the first data point to the end of the list to force a closed loop.

0,00000 -0,17278
0,05000 -0,16098
0,10000 -0,15170
0,15000 -0,13824
0,20000 -0,12830
0,20000 -2,22890
0,15000 -2,25024
0,10000 -2,27128
0,05000 -2,28972
0,00000 -2,30557
0,00000 -0,17278

Then create a "smooth lined" scatter plot of the data.

The result looks like this:

[image: result]

Comment: @Samdar Thank you very much for the suggested edit. Could you explain what you did to make the image appear in the answer?

Comment: *1.* My name is not Samdar. *2.* And to answer your question, click on edit, you'll see how. However images will start to automatically embed into your post if you use `Ctrl`+`G` shortcut (or there is a button next to `{}` ) to upload them once you reach sufficient reputation (if you haven't already).

Comment: @Sardar, sorry for getting your name wrong.  I looked at the edit before I asked the question.  It's fairly non-explanatory, but thanks, maybe it'll become clearer with more rep points.

Comment: @Ana, will this solution work for you?

Comment: See this → https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post